# Delete Last Child Json Nested Object

Tags: jquery, json, object, nested

Sorry my English is a little bad.
I want to delete the last object.I tried in this way did not.
I hope I could tell.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Rizasoylu/hnLadq9v/

My request to delete obj3.

```
var oArray = ["obj1","obj2","obj3"];
var AccessObject = {};
oArray.reduce(function (o, s) { return o[s] = {}; }, AccessObject);


var AccessObject = {}, o = AccessObject;

for (var i = 0; i < oArray.length; i++) 
{
    o = o[oArray[i]] = {};
}
alert(JSON.stringify(AccessObject));
var lastKey = Object.keys(AccessObject).sort().reverse()[0];
delete o[lastKey];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

```
for (var i = 0; i < oArray.length; i++) {
    if (i == oArray.length - 1) {
        o = o[oArray[i]] = genericObject;
    } else {
        o = o[oArray[i]] = {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splice method. Using this javascript method you can remove element. First parameter define the position and you can provide how many element you want to remove as the second argument

```
var oArray = ["obj1","obj2","obj3"];
oArray .splice(2,1);
alert(JSON.stringify(oArray));
```